# axios converts x-www-form-urlencoded to multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I am sending a post request with axios. However, when I check the browser console, I see that the request header is actually `content-type: multipart/form-data`. How can I enforce `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Or does it even matter?

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
// ... removed for conciseness 
return axios.post(`${AUTH_URL}/token`, 
    data,
    {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` objects **always** serialise to `multipart/form-data`. They have to because they support file uploading and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  and `application/json` do not.

If you want to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data you should pass a `URLSearchParams` object instead.

This is described in [the axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

In either case, you shouldn't specify the `Content-Type` in the `headers` since the underlying browser APIs will infer it correctly from the object type passed as the body data.